# Pyspark streaming join then aggregate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, spark-streaming, aggregation

I'm using Pyspark streaming to join and aggregate two data streams. I have a column with "word"s and in another stream I have those words mapped to an integer. I'd like to output the updated sum of those integers for each word.

```
# You can set up whatever streams you want 
# in my actual use case i'm using kafka

# For minimal example I'm running nc in terminal and feeding in words
# nc -lk 9999
s1 = (
    spark.readStream.format("socket")
                    .options(host="localhost", port=9999)
                    .load()
)

# nc -lk 8888
s2 = (
    spark.readStream.format("socket")
                    .options(host="localhost", port=8888)
                    .load()
)

# name columns and add ts for the required watermark
w1 = s1.select(
    fn.col("value").alias("word"),
    fn.window(fn.expr("current_timestamp"), "30 seconds").alias("ts")
).withWatermark("ts", "10 seconds")

w2 = s2.select(
    fn.col("value").alias("word"),
    fn.window(fn.expr("current_timestamp"), "30 seconds").alias("ts"),
    fn.expr("int(rand() * 10)").alias("num")
).withWatermark("ts", "10 seconds")

# Join and aggregate
j = w1.join(
    w2, 
    ["ts", "word"], 
    "left"
).groupBy("word").sum("num")

# errors - "complete" is not supported when using joins
q = j.writeStream.outputMode("complete").foreachBatch(lambda df, _: df.show(truncate=False)).start()
```

I'd like to get the total sum (so far) of `num` for each word. So if the data in the first time window is

| Time | word | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | foo | 1 |
| t1 | foo | 2 |
| t1 | bar | 3 |
| t1 | bar | 4 |

Then the output will be

| word | sum(num) |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 3 |
| bar | 7 |

If the data in the second window is

| Time | word | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t2 | foo | 3 |
| t2 | foo | 4 |
| t2 | bar | 5 |
| t2 | bar | 5 |

Then the output will then be the total across both windows

| word | sum(num) |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 10 |
| bar | 17 |

How do I accomplish this?